socketio listener to get status of function on different thread.(without kafka or rabbit mq)
This is just a poc code.I am trying to get the status of different function running on different thread and I have to add the status to database.But I dont know why this is not working.
`app = create_app()
socketio = SocketIO(app)


# Function whose status you want to track
def long_running_task():
    print("##################long_running_task is running")
    for i in range(10):
        time.sleep(1)  # Simulating a long-running task
        socketio.emit('status_update', {'status': f'Processing... {i + 1}/10'})
    socketio.emit('status_update', {'status': 'Task complete!'})
    print("long_running_task completed")


# Function to listen for status updates and print them to the terminal
@socketio.on('status_update')
def handle_status_update(data):
    print("handle_status_update is running")
    print("data listened")
    print(data['status'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    task_thread = threading.Thread(target=long_running_task)
    status_update_thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_status_update)

    task_thread.start()
    status_update_thread.start()
    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8087)`

